# php artisan make:migration really slow

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

When creating a new migration using the artisan command early on in some (not all) projects, the command is completed almost instantly and back to the prompt.

I have noticed that the file is created almost instantly as expected but the command does not return to the prompt. It can take minutes sometimes!

Does anyone have any suggestions, php setting changes or known reasons this occurs and any way of resolving this?

Comment: My suspicion would be you're doing something on every request (service provider, perhaps) that attempts or makes a network call of some kind.

Comment: There is a possibility this could be it. Is there a way of listing database calls made via this command? To note, the other artisan commands are instant, just making migrations that is slow

Comment: if you're using xampp on a windows machine, it's actually a common issue. Do your `PHP` scripts run slower than expected too?

Comment: Are you working remotely by any chance? I experience a similar issue where artisan commands are instant at my place of employment but very slow at home.

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: @ArianSakhaei using artisan serve

Comment: @msmahon working directly on device

Comment: @UnderDog No not using WSL to host